# Best way to import sass / code from GitHub?

Tags: sass, module, hugo

I'm trying to figure out how Hugo can (automatically) pull the most recent files from a Github folder when running `hugo server`. In particular, I like to pull css files from [Primer CSS](https://github.com/primer/css) by GitHub. What is the best way to implement that, so that I do not always have to update the Primer CSS manually on my Git?

I was thinking modules would be a way (config.yaml):

```
module:
  imports:
    - disable: false
      path: github.com/primer/css
      mounts:
          - source: src/scss
            target: assets/scss/primer
```

However, when adding this to `config.yaml`, it does not appear to work:

```
Error: module "github.com/primer/css" not found; either add it as a Hugo Module or store it in "/Users/user/code/my-theme/themes".: module does not exist
```

Is there any simple best practice in automatically pulling the most recent files from https://github.com/primer/css/(/src) and loading it into the `/assets` folder? Or is the only way to work with npm node modules, like here: https://github.com/lucperkins/hugo-primer

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a long time. The key is to initialize your your site as a "go module" by running `hugo mod init {anything}`. That will create a `go.mod` file. So if you ran `hugo mod init mywebsite` that generate a `go.mod` that looks something like this:

```golang
module mywebsite

go 1.14

require github.com/primer/css v1.0.0 // indirect
```

After that, the modules should work for you.